# Communication between the SmartCard and the Smart Card Reader - Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to implement the communication between the smart card and the smart card reader on the blackberry simulator.

And according I have implemented the `SmartCard` and the `SmartCardSession` class and also the `SmartCardReader` and the `SmartCardReaderSession` class.

I am unable to send the `apdu` for it to communicate. The code snippet is as shown below. I would appreciate all the help in this regard. Please indicate where I am going wrong or what else I have to implement.

```
CommandAPDU commandAPDU = new CommandAPDU( (byte)0x00, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00);
byte[] LcData= {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03};
ResponseAPDU responseAPDU = new ResponseAPDU();

SmartCardReaderSession readerSession= reader.openSession();

readerSession.sendAPDU(commandAPDU, responseAPDU);
```

Comment: How are you declaring / defining the `commandAPDU` and `responseAPDU` objects? Do you get any errors in the log? (Hold down `alt` and type `LGLG` (but in lowercase; `l` looks stupid in most fonts) at the home screen.)

Comment: Hi Sarnold,Thanks for the quick response. CommandAPDU commandAPDU = new CommandAPDU( (byte)0x00, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00); byte[] LcData= {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03}; ResponseAPDU responseAPDU = new ResponseAPDU(); I am not getting any response. I am trying to run it in the simulator and in a testapp. the app wouldn't run when i try to send the apdu. else it works fine.

Comment: I could never get it work on simulator. Try it on real device, i am sure it would be fine. Get back to us in case of any issues. If you can post the entire code/project, I could test it at your behest.